# "Available Form:". Original Delphi Frames with Original unit

Tags: delphi

### Problem:

How can I load frame in `Form1` or sample container in form ?

`FindClass` or `GetClass` is only locality for main form appl-n

I need (maybe) string globaly elemental for `TFrameClass`, next code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TFrameClass = class of TFrame;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);    
  private
    FFrame: TFrame;    
    function StrShowFrame(FrameClassName: string;
      ParentPanel: TWinControl): Boolean;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Base1Frame, Base2Frame, Base3Frame;

function TForm1.StrShowFrame(FrameClassName: string;
  ParentPanel: TWinControl): Boolean;
var
  FrameClass: TClass;
  // Current Frame  (FrameName)
  FrameName: string;    
begin
  Result := False;

  ???   GetClass is only locality for main form in appl-n

  FrameClass := GetClass(FrameClassName);

  if FrameClass = nil then
  begin    
    ShowMessageFmt('Class %s not registered', [FrameClassName]);
    Result := False;
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    begin
      LockWindowUpdate(ParentPanel.Handle);

      if Assigned(FFrame) then
        if FFrame.ClassType = FrameClass then
        begin
          Result := True;
          Exit;  
        end
        else
          FFrame.Destroy; // del previus FrameClass

      try
        FFrame := TFrameClass(FrameClass).Create(nil);
      except
        on E:Exception do
        begin
          Result := True;
          E.Create(E.Message);
          FFrame := nil;
          Exit;
        end;
      end;

      FrameName:= FrameClassName;
      Delete(FrameName, 1, 1); // T-...    
      FFrame.Name := Concat(FrameName, '1');
      FFrame.Parent := ParentPanel;
      FFrame.Align := alClient;    
    end;    
  finally
    LockWindowUpdate(0); 
  end;

  Result := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StrShowFrame('TFr_Base1', Panel1);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  try
    if FFrame <> nil then
      FFrame.Free
    else
      ShowMessage('Class not activ');    
  except

  end;    
end;

end.
```

How can I load frame in `Form1` or sample container in form ?

`FindClass` or `GetClass` is only locality for main form appl-n

I need (maybe) string globaly elemental for `TFrameClass`.

Comment: You use the phrase "only locality" three times, but I have no idea what it means. Could you please try another way of wording your problem. Also, please don't use abbreviations; I assume "appl-n" means "application," but it's not an abbreviation I've ever seen before, and it's making your question harder to understand.

Answer (score 3):

`GetClass()` and `FindClass()` are not local to the MainForm, they are global to the entire RTL as a whole.  Any unit can call `RegisterClass()` and have that class be accessible to any other unit that shares **the same instance** of the RTL.  That last part is important.  A DLL cannot register a class that the EXE uses (and vice versa), unless both projects are compiled with Runtime Packages enabled so they share a single RTL instance.

Comment: "  I assume "appl-n" ". Ya, it`s "application".

Comment: FrameClassName it`s not string parametr for     TFrameClass = class of TFrame but i need `FrameClassName: string` ... with created Frames: UnitName=Base1Frame, FrameClassName=TFr_Base1, FrameName=Fr_Base1, UnitName=Base2Frame, ...2, UnitName=Base3Frame ...3;

Comment: [link] How i can corectly,

Comment: `StrShowFrame(FrameClassName: string; ParentPanel: TWinControl): Boolean;`

Comment: initialization begin RegisterClasses([TFr_Base1]); end; end.